# Aggregate com Sort - MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, classificação

Tenho uma consulta no MongoDB, faço o aggregate para contar quantos itens existem de cada categoria, tudo funciona bem, no entanto não consigo ordenar os dados, que seriam ordenados pelo campo Title. Segue o código, no qual já fiz inúmeras alterações:

```
var aggregate = collection.Aggregate()
            .Match(filters)
            .Group(new BsonDocument { { "_id", "$CategoryId" }, { "count", new BsonDocument("$sum", 1) } })
            .Sort(new BsonDocument("Title", 1));
            //.Project(new BsonDocument { { "Title", 1 }, { "count", 1 } });
```

Comment: Já tentou colocar o Sort depois do Group?

Comment: sim, é q já alterei várias vezes, acabei postando assim, vou até mudar.